# How to parse a date String containing a timezone?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, momentjs, datetime-format

I have date in String:

```
let day = "12/07/1998 12:30 GMT+4"
```

How to convert it into a moment date?
I tried

```
let d = moment(day, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm')
```

But I don't know how to parse the timezone. I could not find it in the [documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/parse-zone/)

Comment: did you check the updated answer for this special case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moment.js doesn't necessarily parse the timezone if the string isn't in either ISO 8601 or RFC 2822 formats. It expects the timezone to be in ±HHmm format, so `GMT+4` is ignored.

If you pass the string to the constructor with no format information, you'll get a warning and maybe it will be parsed correctly and maybe it wont.

If you can't fix the input format at the source, you can fix it at your end (provided you know the format), then provide "Z" in the parse tokens, e.g.:

```js
/* Fix offset like GMT+4 to +0400
 * If offset is 1 digit, pad to 0d00      -8 -> -0800 
 * If offset is 2 digits, pad to dd00    +10 -> +1000
 * If offset is 3 digits, padd to 0ddd  +530 -> +0530
 * If offset is 4 digits, leave as is  +1030 -> +1030
 */
function fixOffset(s) {
  var tz = s.match(/(GMT)([+-])(\d+)$/);
  // If not required format, do nothing
  if (tz.length != 4) return;
  var h = tz[3];
  var offset = h.length == 1? '0' + h + '00' :
               h.length == 2?       h + '00' :
               h.length == 3? '0' + h        : h;
  return s.replace(/GMT[+-]\d+$/, tz[2] + offset);
}

var s = "12/07/1998 12:30 GMT+4";
s = fixOffset(s);

console.log('Fixed format: ' + s);

console.log( moment(s,'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm Z').format('LLLL') );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: nice but too much ternary ununderstandable code, you can use moment built-in methods for that!

Answer (score 2):

## Updated 2018/11/6:

Newer versions of moment expect you to pass timezone format as one of these two options:

**ZZ=>**
`-07:00 -06:00 ... +06:00 +07:00`

Or

**Z =>**
`-0700 -0600 ... +0600 +0700`

[Read More Here..](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/162)

So we need to repair our given *GMT+4* format to match the input case we will use some regex and es6 templating to **reformat** our given date like this:
`DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm ZZ` notice 'ZZ' at the end:

**Demo:**

```js
let date = "12/07/1998 12:30 GMT+4"
let justDayAndTime = date.split(/(GMT(\+|\-)\d+)/)[0].trim()
let zone = date.match(/\d+$/)[0]
let mark = date.match(/(\+|\-)/)[0]
let parsed = `${justDayAndTime} ${mark}${moment(zone,"k").format("HH:mm")}`

let result = moment(parsed,"DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm ZZ")

console.log(result.format('LLLL'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

---

### Answer:

You can use the [format](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) method

```js
moment("12/07/1998 12:30 GMT+4").format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

For more Time Zone control:

https://momentjs.com/timezone/

Comment: This doesn't help with parsing the timezone. All that happens is that moment.js can't recognise the format so throws it to the built-in parser, which most likely treats it as 7 December, not 12 July which is what the OP wants. Including moment.js in the above snippet shows the warning.

Comment: I didn't notice the warning I will try to fix this now

Answer (score 0):

The best way to parse Timezones string, is to use moment timezone.
You have to do like this
        `moment.tz(day)`